# "Machine-readable" list of states in native name

Tags: language, parsing

I'm searching for a list *(xml,json,... preferred)* which contains all sovereign states *(lets define them as the members of the UN only)* in their native name(s).

ISO-Code for state and language are not required, but would be good, too.

There's a human readable list in the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states), but I honestly think that parsing html would be a worst case.

**Is there a freely usable list available for what I need?**

**Edit**: Tried enumerating them with [`RegionInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.regioninfo.aspx) in *.NET*, but "just" got 127 states.

Comment: Did you try using some wmic option???? Go to your cmd and type "wmic" then type "/?". Im not sure but i think I already saw something like that there.

Comment: @Diogo_Rocha: Didn't find anything with wmic, but i think the most information I could get there is about supported windows languages. :/

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the closest you'll get is one of the XML files from here:  http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists.htm

Comment: They sell something which might contain what I need. For 208,00 CHF .....
Sadly the native names are more important than the iso-codes =/

Comment: Yes, unfortunately much of the useful information available from ISO is not free.